# Error in else value on android

Tags: image, if-statement, view, conditional-statements

i want to change visibility when special status

so i do else like that

```
else {  
ImageView image_A_wrong = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

But appear error on eclipse.

Do you know why ?

my imageview

> ```
> <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:src="@drawable/quo100px"
>         android:visibility="gone" />
> ```

Tks advance all

Here my complete file

> package com.example.androidhive;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>      import java.util.HashMap;
>      import java.util.List;
>
> import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
>     import org.json.JSONArray;
>      import org.json.JSONException;
>      import org.json.JSONObject;
>
> import android.app.ListActivity;
>      import android.app.ProgressDialog;
>     import android.content.Intent;
>      import android.os.AsyncTask;
>      import android.os.Bundle;
>      import android.util.Log;
>      import android.view.View;
>      import android.widget.AdapterView;
>      import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
>      import android.widget.ImageView;
>      import android.widget.ListAdapter;
>      import android.widget.ListView;
>      import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
>      import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class quoPAPIERCORD extends ListActivity {
>
> ```
>   // Progress Dialog
>   private ProgressDialog pDialog;
>
>   // Creating JSON Parser object
>   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
>
>   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
>
>   // url to get all products list
>   private static String url_all_products_quo = >"http://192.168.1.81/php/android/get_all_quotidiens.php";
>
>   // JSON Node names
>   private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
>   private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
>   private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
>   private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
>   private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
>   private static String TAG_CU = "cu";
>
>   // products JSONArray
>   JSONArray products = null;
>
>   @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.quotidiens);
>
>       // Hashmap for ListView
>       productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>
>       // Loading products in Background Thread
>       new LoadAllProducts().execute();
>
>       // Get listview
>       ListView lv = getListView();
>
>       // on seleting single product
>       // launching Edit Product Screen
>       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>
>           @Override
>           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                   int position, long id) {
>               // getting values from selected ListItem
>               String pid = ((TextView) >view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
>                       .toString();
>
>               // Starting new intent
>               Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
>                       EditProductActivity.class);
>               // sending pid to next activity
>               in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
>
>               // starting new activity and expecting some response back
>               startActivityForResult(in, 100);
>           }
>       });
>
>   }
>
>   // Response from Edit Product Activity
>   @Override
>   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>       // if result code 100
>       if (resultCode == 100) {
>           // if result code 100 is received 
>           // means user edited/deleted product
>           // reload this screen again
>           Intent intent = getIntent();
>           finish();
>           startActivity(intent);
>       }
>
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
>    * */
>   class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>
>       /**
>        * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
>        * */
>       @Override
>       protected void onPreExecute() {
>           super.onPreExecute();
>           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(quoPAPIERCORD.this);
>           pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
>           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>           pDialog.setCancelable(false);
>           pDialog.show();
>       }
>
>       /**
>        * getting All products from url
>        * */
>       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
>           // Building Parameters
>           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>           // getting JSON string from URL
>           JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products_quo, >"GET", params);
>
>           // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
>           Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
>
>           try {
>               // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
>               int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>
>               if (success == 1) {
>                   // products found
>                   // Getting Array of Products
>                   products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
>
>                   // looping through All Products
>                   for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
>                       JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
>
>                       // Storing each json item in variable
>                       String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
>                       String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
>                       String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
>                       String cu = c.getString(TAG_CU);
>                       /////////////
>                       if (cu.equals("1")) {
>                           cu = "oui";
>                       } else {
>                           ImageView image_A_wrong = (ImageView) >findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
>                           image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>                       }
>                       // creating new HashMap
>                       HashMap<String, String> map = new >HashMap<String, String>();
>
>                       // adding each child node to HashMap key => >value
>                       map.put(TAG_PID, id);
>                       map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
>                       map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
>                       map.put(TAG_CU, cu);
>
>                       // adding HashList to ArrayList
>                       productsList.add(map);
>                   }
>               } else {
>                   // no products found
>                   // Launch Add New product Activity
>                   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
>                           NewProductActivity.class);
>                   // Closing all previous activities
>                   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
>                   startActivity(i);
>               }
>           } catch (JSONException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>
>
>
>           return null;
>       }
>
>       /**
>        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
>        * **/
>
>
>       protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>           // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
>           pDialog.dismiss();
>           // updating UI from Background Thread
>           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>               public void run() {
>                   /**
>                    * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
>                    * */
>                   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
>                           quoPAPIERCORD.this, productsList,
>                           R.layout.list_item, new String[] { >TAG_PID,
>                                   TAG_NAME, >TAG_PRICE, TAG_CU},
>                           new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, >R.id.price, R.id.cu });
>                   // updating listview
>                   setListAdapter(adapter);
>               }
>           });
>
>       }
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="5px"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10px" 
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="left"  />

    <!-- price Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5px" 
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textColor="#C00000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/quo100px"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5px" 
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textColor="#C00000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"  />


      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5px" 
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textColor="#C00000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"  />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5px" 
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textColor="#C00000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error comes..?? Can you specify it.? So, I got better idea..

Comment: Tks for your reply. you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811776/android-imageview-setvisibility

Comment: Nobody know why ? tks advance

Comment: Hi all. I have not found yet solution . anybody can try to help me ? tks advance

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811776/android-imageview-setvisibility), You can't access UI (Textview, Edittext, ImageView, etc) inside **DoInBackgroud**. Do it on either **OnPostExecute** or **OnProgressUpdate** method

Edit: Change this

```
if (cu.equals("1"))
{
   cu = "oui";
} 
else
{
   ImageView image_A_wrong = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

to

```
if (cu.equals("1"))
{
   cu = "oui";
} 
else
{
   cu = "pas";
}
```

then add this to your **OnPostExecute()**

Edit 2: Seeing your code I've somewhat narrowed your error. the above code must be like

Declare the string **cu** globally and then try the follwing

```
ImageView image_A_wrong = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
if(cu.equals("pas"))
{
    image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
    image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Tks Mojo for your answer. so i m new on android app, how i can do like you said ?

Comment: You are using the `else` part DoInBackground, right? Take it from there and paste it at OnPostExecute method

Comment: My idea is show image when value in database is present. if not don't show image.

Comment: ok there is no error on script but when it's "pas" my imageview appear.. :(

Comment: So for each item in the list you wanna set an image?

Comment: no, i just want if value is "pas" show image. not do not show.
i post my list item

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this too. See my answer now

Comment: I correct to if(TAG_CU.equals("pas"))
   {
       ImageView image_A_wrong = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   else
   {
    ImageView image_A_wrong = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }

But crash apps

Comment: i change else value to another if (TAG_CU.equals("oui")) ->View.VISIBLE  not crash app, but image are all time show... :'(

Comment: it's like setVisibility is not take it

Comment: You need an array to set value to each item in the list then use the same if condition to check inside a for loop. then it'll definitely work

Comment: Anymore explanation, msg me at www.facebook.com/mojo723

Comment: Can you send skype ? we don't have facebook account ? mp if you want

Comment: Mojo, do you have see my bug ? tks advance

Comment: i WAS SICK FOR TWO DAYS, TOMO i'LL SEND IT BACK TO YOU. sORRY MAN

Comment: Hi Mojo. i hope you are doing better.

Comment: Hi Mojo. i hope you are doing well. do you have news about my bug ? tks advance

Comment: Tks mojo. you must connect to skype for i receive that you send :)

Comment: Mojo can you send me per email ?